# Change the filename when uploading a file

Tags: javascript, file-upload

Is there a way to change the name of the file to a GUID after the real file has been selected and is ready to be uploaded?

The user is wanting to leave the old file(s) in the repository on the server, and when a new file is uploaded, it won't overwrite the old file.

So my thoughts are to simply change the filename after selected, but before the upload is performed.

Comment: Why the down vote?  if you don't have anything to add, then just move on.

Comment: I think it might help to at least tell us what server-side language you're using and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Because you should handle this server-side, as even random client-side generated file names might cause a collision of file names theoretically.

Comment: as indicated in the tags, javascript

Comment: So it's a nodejs server?

Comment: Connum - there is no post processing available on the server.  The risk of a filename collision by using a GUID is far less a risk than allowing the user the ability to simply and blindly overwriting the single instance of the file on the CDN.

Comment: node.js...   no,   pure javascript on the client.  'server' is not a server, it is a CDN repository, just a file dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data you get from a File input are readonly. You cannot change `file.name`; You can use different hidden inputs/variables and supply that to the server so that it can rename it to that later.
Or you can create a new instance of `File()` and supply it with the new name, and upload that file instead.

Edit: [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/03vzqaw8/)

Comment: This 'create a new instance of File()'    do you have a code sample of this

Comment: Edited the answer to add a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/03vzqaw8/

Comment: Outstanding - thank you!!